# How do I filter in PowerAutomate to return values in an Excel where the date equals yesterday?

Tags: excel, power-automate, powerapps

I've been scouring the Internet for an answer to this question, but with no avail. Here's the situation: I want to create a flow in PowerAutomate that will run every day and send a list of all items with a submitted date of yesterday in an Excel column.

My flow is currently structured liked this:
List rows present in a table with DateTime Format set to ISO 8601 -->[Filter Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNo0Z.png) --> Compose

No matter how many times I try, I can not get the compose function to return the correct number of items with a timestamp of yesterday. For additional context, the source data is in EST in the MM/D/YYYY format. How do I get this filter to return all items with a submission date of yesterday?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I've tried using the addDays(utcNow(),-1,'yyyy-MM-dd') but to no avail. I'm also not sure if the timezone is playing role with any of this? I've also tried to format the timestamp to match, but I have been really struggling with this.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `addDays(utcNow(),-1,'MM/d/yyyy')` to match your source format? When the flow runs, what value do you get for `Timestamp` in the array?

Comment: @SamNseir, I changed the format of the filter array to be addDays(utcNow(),01, 'mm-d-yyyy') to match my source data that is in the MM/D/YYYY format based off your comment, but I'm still getting an output of 0. The array is reading the timestamp as "YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000Z" which I'm guessing is because I have the DateTime Format in the filter array set to ISO 8601. I set it to ISO 8601 because with no format there, the date was being read as a number by the flow. Any idea what's up? I'm guessing it has to do with the format of addDays not matching the format of the date?

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing the timestamp format - posted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure both sides of filter array have the same date format.
For the left side, try this expression:

```
formatDateTime(item()?['Timestamp'], 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

And use the same format for the right side:

```
addDays(utcNow(), -1, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Comment: Thanks for this @SamNseir! I tried this out, and I'm still getting an output of 0. Here's how it reads: Filter array From value (excel) and then I have formatDateTime(item()?['Timestamp'], 1, 'yyyy-MM-DD') on the left, and the right is addDays(utcNow(),-1,'yyyy-MM-dd'). The output of this should be 2, but it's returning 0.

Comment: Can you click on the `...` of the Filter Array and select `Peek code` and then share what it says. Also I guessed  this bit `item()?['Timestamp']` check if I have that right. If possible to see a row of the array that would help too (in the flow run output).

Comment: Hi Sam, I'm going to post some images in an answer below for you to take a look at!

Comment: It needs to be `yyyy-MM-dd` and not `yyy-MM-DD`

Comment: Please help mark this answer as accepted for the benefit of all.

Answer (score 0):

that info is below:
The item()?['Timestamp']looks correct based on what PowerAutomate
This is the code for the filter array:
{

```
"inputs": {

    "from": "@outputs('List_rows_present_in_a_table')?['body/value']",

    "where": "@equals(formatDateTime(item()?['Timestamp'], 'yyyy-MM-DD'), addDays(utcNow(), -1, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))"

},

"description": "Left: formatDateTime(item()?['Timestamp'],'yyyy-MM-DD')",

"metadata": {

    "operationMetadataId": "4774a1c0-089a-43a7-acfa-6fe409945246"

}
```

}

Here's what the timestamp looks like in the source table:
[Timestamp Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wey8U.png)

Here's the compose function: [Compose Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FnbI.png)

Here's the filter array: [Filter Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwSm6.png)

Comment: Thanks. It needs to be `yyyy-MM-dd` and not `yyy-MM-DD`

Comment: Perfect! That worked. Thank you sooooo much. Couple of quick follow-up questions: the timestamp is in Eastern Time. Will I need to convert it to Eastern time, or does the flow work as is? Second, I can use and() to filter based off of this and a second condition, right?

Comment: You don't need to worry about timezones normally, just know that Power Automate will run in UTC time, so ensure it the flow runs when it is the same day in Eastern time. Regarding And in the Filter array, you'll need to update the left side as `and(equals(formatDateTime(item()?['Timestamp'], 'yyyy-MM-DD'), addDays(utcNow(), -1, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) , {{second condition}}) ` and your left side as an expression `true`

Comment: Thank you so much, Sam! You've been such a big help. One last thing I am trying to figure out (and let me know if this should be a separate topic) - how do I do what is basically a countifs but in PowerAutomate? Basically, I there are 5 different groups that could submit responses, and I want to count each of them every day. Would I need to do 5 parallel branches, each with their own filter array? I also tried doing a switch, but the output was strange to me.

Comment: Just use `length( yourArray )`. Use the Filter Array as before with your condition, and after check its length.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Would those just be 5 separate branches of the flow then (if that's the different groups I'm trying to count for)?

Comment: Correct - if I'm visualizing what you are after correctly :)

Comment: Thanks Sam! Final final question - is there a way to have PowerAutomate pull yesterday's data only if the day is Tuesday-Friday and pull Friday's data on Monday? The use case is - people would only need to know about form submissions from the week but I cannot think of how to code that. Is there a way for PowerAutomate to detect if a day is a weekday?

Comment: `addDays(utcNow(), if(equals(dayOfWeek(utcNow()), 1), -3, -1), 'yyyy-MM-dd')`